# How do I create a vertical menubar in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, menubar

I am trying to make a vertical menubar but I don`t know how, basically a normal menubar but just on the left side of the gui. Is it even possible?

Comment: Have you tried using the tkinter `Menu` widget? If this isn't what you are looking for, perhaps you can provide an example of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a vertical menu bar that attaches to the left or right side of the frame, I don't think you can do that with the default tkinter.Menu object since you aren't able to call .pack() or to change it's anchor point.

You likely will need to create your own menu class. You'll want to use a tk.Frame to hold your tkinter.Button and tkinter.OptionMenu widgets, which you bind to their respective functions using the command option. I would suggest that you extend tk.Frame:

```
class VerticalMenu(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
      #Do other init here to add your menu items
```

Example of a command bind:

```
def DoSomething():
   print('Hello World')

frame = tkinter.Frame(parent) #Parent will probably be your master tk.Tk object
frame.pack(anchor = 'nw') #Anchors the frame to the top-left corner, use 'ne' for top-right.
button = tkinter.Button(frame, label = 'Button Text', command = DoSomething)
button.pack(anchor = 'n') #This will anchor the button to the top of the frame, giving you your verticality
```